# Cannot run without administrator privileges

Tags: lync, microsoft-office-365

I have a user who is running `Lync`, but unless it is run as an administrator, she cannot log in. Her `Lync` account is fine and other standard users do not have this issue.

I have been able to log in by logging on the machine as a domain admin and also by logging into her user account and running Lync as an administrator.

This issue occurs with both `Lync 2010` and `Lync 2013`. The OS is `Windows 7 Professional`.

**Edit:**

We have just found out that if she logs onto other machines, she can log on fine. It seems the issue is local to that laptop.

Comment: Any particular reason against reimaging?

Comment: @FalconMomot No, but it would be great to know why first. Reimaging is fast becoming an option.

Comment: It sounds like the kind of miscellaneous random corruption or just the wrong combination of things that would be way more effort to root out than it's worth... probably a few files (who knows which) have the wrong ownership or something.

Comment: Can you log in with a standard domain user account on her machine and then log into Lync?  You mention your domain admin works, but what about a normal account on her computer besides her?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same problem.  Support has said it is just a software issue.  They mentioned it might be a conflict between Office and Lync.  I have completely uninstalled Office and Lync; reinstalled Lync; no good.  I have completely uninstalled Office and Lync; reinstalled Office 2013 with Lync; no good.

What I have found is an order to run the Office programs.
1) Run Outlook.
2) Run Lync as administrator.

If you do them in the opposite order, Outlook will require you to run it as administrator.  When it is run as administrator, the search functionality is no longer available.

I believe Lync is accessing Outlook's files and does not have the correct permissions.  This leads to the conflicts and having to run Lync as administrator.